# Problems in compiling code due to the modulus operator

Tags: c++, c++11

I have written a program to store a number (which is predefined by the programmer) in form of digits in an array.

For example, if I want to store a number 1234 in array arrx[4], then its elements would be:

```
arr[0] = 1
arr[1] = 2
arr[2] = 3
arr[3] = 4
```

I try to achieve this using the below piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arrx[4];    // Stores the individual digits of number as array
    int digx = 4;   // Total number of digits in number
    int i;
    long int dupx = 1234;  // Number which has to be stored in array
    for(i = digx-1; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        arrx[digx-i-1] = int(dupx/pow(10,i));
        dupx = dupx%(pow(10, i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I try to compile the above code, I get the following error message:

> error: invalid operands of types 'long int' and 'double' to binary 'operator%'

The only conclusion which I was able to draw from above error was that the problem is with the modulus operator.

Therefore, I have following questions in my mind

1. What exactly is the problem with the code containing modulus operator?
2. How can I fix this?

I am using Code::Blocks version 17.12 with GNU GCC as my compiler.

Comment: Not directly related to the problem, but instead of assuming 4 digits, you might want to use `digx = 1 + (int)log(dupx)/log(10);`

Comment: @GauravSingh: Na, that's evil. To count digits use the `/=10` loop idiom.

Comment: @Bathsheba And why is that evil? Because of time taken for calculation?

Comment: @GauravSingh: Because floating point mathematics is not designed for that sort of application (it could wind up being slower for short numbers too.)

Comment: Never use floating point when you want exact numbers. Floating point values are approximations which will, in most cases, not be equal to the exact value you want them to represent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can only use `%` with integers, and `pow` produces floating-point numbers.

You could write an integer power function, or use a predefined table, but it's simpler to reverse the order of construction and start with the rightmost digit:

```
int main()
{
   int arrx[4];    //stores the individual digits of number as array
   int digx = 4;   //total number of digits in number
   long int dupx = 1234;  //number which has to be stored in array
   for(int i = 0; i < digx; i++)
   {
        arrx[digx-i-1] = dupx%10;
        dupx = dupx/10;
   }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

`std::pow` in its various guises returns a floating point type, even if the arguments are integral types.

Since `%` requires integral arguments, compilation will fail.

Using `(long)(pow(10,i))` is one fix, checking of course that `(long)` is long enough. Note though that even under IEEE754 `pow` is not required to return the best floating point value possible, so the truncation to `long` can occasionally be harmful; perhaps `std::round` followed by the cast to `long` is to be preferred. Although the current fashion is to consider any implementation of `pow` that breaks for integral arguments to be defective.

In your case though I'd be tempted to define

```
constexpr/*use const on earlier standards*/ int powers[] = {1, 10, 100, 1000};
```

and index appropriately.

Comment: At last, a well set out answer. Nice text, good code, great answerer. Means it's easy to upvote. Thank you.